# Find out which friends have photo tags with FQL query

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of friends that are tagged in a photo. I'm not interested in how many, what photo or anything else - just a yes or no.

The following query tries to get every tag associated with a user in my friend's list. I would prefer to limit it to one result for each user since the results are too large any other way.

```
SELECT text, subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=58015959)
```

Any ideas? I'm open to using the Graph API if that works too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy and effecient way to get a yes/no answer to this query in FQL.

You can, however, query `http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/photos`. I was over-complicating this step and missed the fact that `/photos` only returns photos that the user ID is tagged in rather than all of their uploaded images.

Comment: This only returns the photos that the user chose to allow on the "Photos of You" section. Any tagged photo that doesn't show up there won't be returned in this request.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of friends who have been tagged in a photo:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN 
   (SELECT subject FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN 
       (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
    LIMIT {n} 1000 )
```

If you've got a lot of friends who are active taggers, you'll need to iterate this query over `{n}`, where `{n}` = 1000 * number of times you've run the query + 1.

Comment: That does limit it to one result per person, but the result of the second query (from photo_tag) is simply too big to return all of my friends. In my case, I get about 2,400 results and it stops at 8 friends. I need to find a way to limit that second query.
I saw some people use php's strpos in the FQL query but haven't had luck with that.

Comment: See my edit above. `strpos` would only help if you wanted to limit your query only to look for one specific tag.